# How can I rewrite this javascript code, so that it will refer to every optionbox?

Tags: javascript

How can I rewrite this javascript code, so that it will refer to every optionbox (not only the first one)?

```
<html>
<div id="form123">
    <select id="day" name="day">
        <option value="abc" name="abc" id="abc">abc</option>
        <option value="other" name="other" id="other">other...</option>
    </select>
    <select id="day" name="day">
        <option value="abc" name="abc" id="abc">abc</option>
        <option value="other" name="other" id="other">other...</option>
    </select>
    <select id="day" name="day">
        <option value="abc" name="abc" id="abc">abc</option>
        <option value="other" name="other" id="other">other...</option>
    </select>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var selectmenu=document.getElementById("day")
        selectmenu.onchange=function(){
            var chosenoption=this.options[this.selectedIndex]
            if (chosenoption.value=="other"){
                var entered_date = window.prompt("Enter the date","");
                document.getElementById('other').value = entered_date;
                document.getElementById('other').text = entered_date;
            }
        }
    </script>
</div>
</html>
```

So far, dialogbox shows up only when I choose the first optionbox.

I want to dialogbox show up even if I choose another optionbox.

In the future, optionboxes will be added dynamically.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`ID` must be unique. I suggest to use a function on every `select` on change event and pass `this` as parameter like:

```js
function changeDate(obj) {
  var chosenoption = obj.options[obj.selectedIndex];
  if (chosenoption.value == "other") {
    var winProVal = window.prompt("Enter the date", "");
    if (winProVal != null) {
      obj.options[obj.value].value = obj.options[obj.value].text = winProVal;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<select class="day" name="day" onchange='changeDate(this);'>
  <option value="abc" name="abc" id="abc">abc</option>
  <option value="other" name="other" id="other">other...</option>
</select>
<select class="day" name="day" onchange='changeDate(this);'>
  <option value="abc" name="abc" id="abc">abc</option>
  <option value="other" name="other" id="other">other...</option>
</select>
<select class="day" name="day" onchange='changeDate(this);'>
  <option value="abc" name="abc" id="abc">abc</option>
  <option value="other" name="other" id="other">other...</option>
</select>
```

`this` refers to the element. Also change `ID` with class.

Comment: you have an error... you only fill the first input! doesnt matter wich selection you choose. guess it has to be `this.getElementById(...)` or some like that... i dont really know

Comment: ps: you could also put the if in one row like `obj.options[obj.value].value=obj.options[obj.value].text=window.prompt("Enter the date", "");` or in vars like `opt.value=opt.text=window.prompt("Enter the date", "");`

Comment: And your new else branch does nothing?

Answer (score 1):

IDs are supposed to be unique (so are names). You may define class of elements and change your js accordingly..

```
<html>
<div id="form123">
    <select id="day" name="day" class="day">
        <option value="abc" name="abc1" id="abc1">abc</option>
        <option value="other" name="other1" id="other1">other...</option>
    </select>
    <select id="day" name="day" class="day">
        <option value="abc" name="abc2" id="abc2">abc</option>
        <option value="other" name="other2" id="other2">other...</option>
    </select>
    <select id="day" name="day" class="day">
        <option value="abc" name="abc3" id="abc3">abc</option>
        <option value="other" name="other3" id="other3">other...</option>
    </select>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var selectmenu=document.getElementsByClassName("day");
        for (var i = 0; i < selectmenu.length; ++i) {
            selectmenu[i].onchange=function(){
            var chosenoption=this.options[this.selectedIndex]
                if (chosenoption.value=="other"){
                    var entered_date = window.prompt("Enter the date","");
                    this.options[1].value = entered_date;
                    this.options[1].text = entered_date;
                }
            }
        }
    </script>
</div>
</html>
```

Comment: go some deeper... `id='abc' and id='other'` are not unique

Comment: @vp_arth Thanks. I just focused on making the popup work... Now it's fixed.